# Why is the following Java NIO API so slow when compared to netty

Tags: java, scala, performance, netty, nio

I have the following JAVA implementation to create a simple web server using the NIO API.

```scala
package zion

import java.net._
import java.nio.ByteBuffer
import java.nio.channels._

object NHello {

  import java.nio.CharBuffer
  import java.nio.charset.Charset

  def helloWorldBytes: ByteBuffer = Charset
    .forName("ISO-8859-1")
    .newEncoder
    .encode(CharBuffer.wrap(httpResponse("NHello World\n")))

  def httpResponse(content: String): String = {
    val rn = "\r\n"
    List(
      "HTTP/1.1 200 OK",
      "Content-Type: text/html",
      "Connection: Keep-Alive",
      s"Content-Length: ${content.length()}",
      rn + content
    ).mkString(rn)
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val port    = 8080
    val address = new InetSocketAddress(port)

    // Server Socket Channel
    val serverSocketChannel = ServerSocketChannel.open()
    serverSocketChannel.bind(address)
    serverSocketChannel.configureBlocking(false)

    // Selector
    val selector = Selector.open()
    serverSocketChannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT)

    while (true) {
      selector.select()
      val iterator = selector.selectedKeys().iterator()
      while (iterator.hasNext) {
        val key = iterator.next()
        if (key.isAcceptable) {
          val channel = serverSocketChannel.accept()
          channel.write(helloWorldBytes)
          channel.close()
        }

      }
      iterator.remove()
    }

    sys.addShutdownHook({
      println("Shutting down...")
      serverSocketChannel.close()
    })

    println("Exiting...")
  }
}
```

Using `wrk` I get around a few thousand requests per second.

```
wrk -t12 -c100 -d10s http://127.0.0.1:8080
```

This seems like a bit too slow when compared to Netty. With Netty I am able to get at least 10 ~ 15 times better throughput. Considering Netty is also built on top of NIO what am I doing wrong?

Are there some obvious performance optimizations that I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some further searching and analysis I have finally figured out all the problems in this above code.

```scala
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val port    = 8080
    val address = new InetSocketAddress(port)

    val serverSocketChannel = ServerSocketChannel.open()
    serverSocketChannel.bind(address)
    serverSocketChannel.configureBlocking(false)

    val selector = Selector.open()
    serverSocketChannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT)

    while (true) {
      selector.select()
      val iterator = selector.selectedKeys().iterator()
      while (iterator.hasNext) {
        val key = iterator.next()
        if (key.isAcceptable) {
          val channel = serverSocketChannel.accept()
          // 1. Blocking Write
          channel.write(helloWorldBytes)
          // 2. Blocking Close
          channel.close()
        }

      }
      iterator.remove()
    }

    sys.addShutdownHook({
      println("Shutting down...")
      serverSocketChannel.close()
    })

    println("Exiting...")
  }
}
```

The main problems were that

**1. Blocking Write**
Because of the blocking write call, unless the bytes are written into the stream I was not able to accept more connections. So those connections are just lying idle, thus affecting the performance of the webserver

**2. Blocking Close**
The `close` call is also blocking and takes time to complete. Again unless the connection is closed, no new requests are accepted and no accepted connections are responded.

There is another problem in closing the connection: Creating a new connection is expensive and tools like `wrk` etc. don't kill the connection automatically after making one request. Closing it on the server is after each request also becomes a performance killer and thus affects your benchmarks.

Here is an alternative "Highly performant" implementation

```scala
package zion

import java.io.IOException
import java.net.InetSocketAddress
import java.nio.ByteBuffer
import java.nio.channels.{
  AsynchronousChannelGroup,
  AsynchronousServerSocketChannel,
  AsynchronousSocketChannel,
  CompletionHandler
}
import java.util.concurrent.{Executors, TimeUnit}

/**
  * This is potentially as fast as it can get using NIO APIs.
  */
object HelloAsyncNIO {
  // Create a thread pool for the socket channel
  // It would be better to have probably only one thread for events.
  // That pool could be shared betwee the SocketServer and in future SocketClients.
  private val group =
    AsynchronousChannelGroup.withThreadPool(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(24))

  // Socket to accept connections
  private val serverSocketChannel = AsynchronousServerSocketChannel.open(group)

  // Port to be used to connect
  private val PORT = 8081

  // Flag to handle logging
  private val ENABLE_LOGGING = false

  /**
    * Contains utilities to manage read/write on the socket channels
    */
  object NIOBuffer {
    def helloWorldBytes: ByteBuffer = Charset
      .forName("ISO-8859-1")
      .newEncoder
      .encode(CharBuffer.wrap(httpResponse("NHello World\n")))

    def httpResponse(content: String): String = {
      val rn = "\r\n"
      List(
        "HTTP/1.1 200 OK",
        "Content-Type: text/html",
        "Connection: Keep-Alive",
        s"Content-Length: ${content.length()}",
        rn + content
      ).mkString(rn)
    }
    private val writeByteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(helloWorldBytes)
    private val readByteBuffer  = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(1024 * 2) // 2kb
    def read(
        socket: AsynchronousSocketChannel
    )(h: CompletionHandler[Integer, AsynchronousSocketChannel]): Unit =
      socket.read(readByteBuffer.duplicate(), socket, h)
    def write(
        socket: AsynchronousSocketChannel
    )(h: CompletionHandler[Integer, AsynchronousSocketChannel]): Unit =
      socket.write(writeByteBuffer.duplicate(), socket, h)
  }

  // Generic async completion handler
  case class Handle[V, A](cb: (V, A) => Unit) extends CompletionHandler[V, A] {
    override def completed(result: V, attachment: A): Unit =
      cb(result, attachment)
    override def failed(cause: Throwable, attachment: A): Unit = {
      cause match {
        case e: IOException => log(e.getMessage)
        case _              => cause.printStackTrace()
      }
    }
  }

  // Logging utility
  def log(input: Any*): Unit = {
    if (ENABLE_LOGGING) println(input.map(_.toString).mkString(", "))
  }

  private val onAccept
      : Handle[AsynchronousSocketChannel, AsynchronousServerSocketChannel] =
    Handle[AsynchronousSocketChannel, AsynchronousServerSocketChannel](
      (socket, server) => {
        log("\nACCEPT")

        // Accept new connections immediately
        server.accept(serverSocketChannel, onAccept)

        // Read from the current socket
        NIOBuffer.read(socket)(onRead)
      }
    )

  private val onRead: Handle[Integer, AsynchronousSocketChannel] =
    Handle[Integer, AsynchronousSocketChannel]((bytes, socket) => {
      log("READ", bytes)

      // EOF, meaning connection can be closed
      if (bytes == -1) socket.close()

      // Some data was read and now we can respond back
      else if (bytes > 0) NIOBuffer.write(socket)(onWrite)

    })

  private val onWrite: Handle[Integer, AsynchronousSocketChannel] =
    Handle[Integer, AsynchronousSocketChannel]((bytes, socket) => {
      log("WRITE", bytes)

      // Read from the socket
      NIOBuffer.read(socket)(onRead)
    })

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    // Setup socket channel
    serverSocketChannel.bind(new InetSocketAddress(PORT))
    serverSocketChannel.accept(serverSocketChannel, onAccept)

    // Making the main thread wait
    group.awaitTermination(Long.MaxValue, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
  }
}
```

Comment: Is `performant` a valid English word? :)

Answer (score -2):

Lot of, basically you're using NIO in 'blocking' way. Check this:

https://bedrin.livejournal.com/204307.html
https://crunchify.com/java-nio-non-blocking-io-with-server-client-example-java-nio-bytebuffer-and-channels-selector-java-nio-vs-io/

Comment: Can you explain what part of their implementation is _blocking_? How would they make it non blocking?

Comment: Actually I have copied almost the same code in that link. What is blocking?

Comment: I actually looked at the example, the server would just crash as soon as the first request was responded to.

Comment: Looking at the accepted answer, the author of this was probably pointing to the right direction but fell short of providing meaningful explanation, right?